# Issue with fig=TRUE in Sweave RStudio

Tags: plot, knitr, sweave, markdown, rstudio

I do not receive plots using the fig=TRUE in the chunks. Rather i receive an 'undefined control sequence' error.
 Consider a simple code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
<<fig=TRUE>>=
plot(rnorm(100,0,1))
@
\end{document}
```

I also recieve '! LaTeX Error: File `pro1-001' not found.' where pro1 is the name of the file

Here are the log errors

```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...\Ginput@path \set@curr@file 
                                                  {#1}\edef \uq@curr@file {\...
l.11 \includegraphics{pro1-001}

>The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

>! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...e \expandafter {\@curr@file 
                                                  }}\expandafter \filename@p...
l.11 \includegraphics{pro1-001}

>The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

>! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \unquote@name 

>l.11 \includegraphics{pro1-001}

>The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

>! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \quote@name 

>l.11 \includegraphics{pro1-001}

>The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

>! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \quote@name 

>l.11 \includegraphics{pro1-001}

>The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


>! LaTeX Error: File `pro1-001' not found.



See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

>l.11 \includegraphics{pro1-001}

>I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

log errors for empty doc

```
eThis is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.3.18)  10 NOV 2019 20:41
entering extended mode
**./pro1.tex
(pro1.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(C:\I\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\I\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (C:\I\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\I\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
) (C:\I\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2019/07/20 v1.3b Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\I\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (C:\I\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

(C:\I\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/share/texmf/tex/latex\Sweave.sty
Package: Sweave 

(C:\I\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (C:\I\tex/latex/fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty
Package: fancyvrb 2019/10/22

Style option: `fancyvrb' v3.3 <2019/10/22> (tvz)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count88
\FV@InFile=\read1
\FV@TabBox=\box27
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count89
\FV@StepNumber=\count90
\FV@OutFile=\write3
)
(C:\I\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 79.
 (C:\I\tex/latex/base\ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
Now handling font encoding TS1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding TS1

(C:\I\tex/latex/base\ts1enc.dfu
File: ts1enc.dfu 2019/07/11 v1.2j UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A2 (decimal 162)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00A4 (decimal 164)
   defining Unicode char U+00A5 (decimal 165)
   defining Unicode char U+00A6 (decimal 166)
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00A8 (decimal 168)
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AC (decimal 172)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00AF (decimal 175)
   defining Unicode char U+00B0 (decimal 176)
   defining Unicode char U+00B1 (decimal 177)
   defining Unicode char U+00B2 (decimal 178)
   defining Unicode char U+00B3 (decimal 179)
   defining Unicode char U+00B4 (decimal 180)
   defining Unicode char U+00B5 (decimal 181)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+00B9 (decimal 185)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+00BC (decimal 188)
   defining Unicode char U+00BD (decimal 189)
   defining Unicode char U+00BE (decimal 190)
   defining Unicode char U+00D7 (decimal 215)
   defining Unicode char U+00F7 (decimal 247)
   defining Unicode char U+0192 (decimal 402)
   defining Unicode char U+02C7 (decimal 711)
   defining Unicode char U+02D8 (decimal 728)
   defining Unicode char U+02DD (decimal 733)
   defining Unicode char U+0E3F (decimal 3647)
   defining Unicode char U+2016 (decimal 8214)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+203B (decimal 8251)
   defining Unicode char U+203D (decimal 8253)
   defining Unicode char U+2044 (decimal 8260)
   defining Unicode char U+204E (decimal 8270)
   defining Unicode char U+2052 (decimal 8274)
   defining Unicode char U+20A1 (decimal 8353)
   defining Unicode char U+20A4 (decimal 8356)
   defining Unicode char U+20A6 (decimal 8358)
   defining Unicode char U+20A9 (decimal 8361)
   defining Unicode char U+20AB (decimal 8363)
   defining Unicode char U+20AC (decimal 8364)
   defining Unicode char U+20B1 (decimal 8369)
   defining Unicode char U+2103 (decimal 8451)
   defining Unicode char U+2116 (decimal 8470)
   defining Unicode char U+2117 (decimal 8471)
   defining Unicode char U+211E (decimal 8478)
   defining Unicode char U+2120 (decimal 8480)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2126 (decimal 8486)
   defining Unicode char U+2127 (decimal 8487)
   defining Unicode char U+212E (decimal 8494)
   defining Unicode char U+2190 (decimal 8592)
   defining Unicode char U+2191 (decimal 8593)
   defining Unicode char U+2192 (decimal 8594)
   defining Unicode char U+2193 (decimal 8595)
   defining Unicode char U+2329 (decimal 9001)
   defining Unicode char U+232A (decimal 9002)
   defining Unicode char U+2422 (decimal 9250)
   defining Unicode char U+25E6 (decimal 9702)
   defining Unicode char U+25EF (decimal 9711)
   defining Unicode char U+266A (decimal 9834)
   defining Unicode char U+27E8 (decimal 10216)
   defining Unicode char U+27E9 (decimal 10217)
   defining Unicode char U+FEFF (decimal 65279)
))
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 349.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 350.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 351.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 352.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 353.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 354.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 355.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 356.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 357.
Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 358.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 359.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 360.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 361.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 362.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 363.
Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 364.
Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 365.
Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 366.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 367.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 368.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 369.
Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 370.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 371.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 372.

Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 373.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 374.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 375.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 376.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 377.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 378.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 379.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 380.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 381.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 382.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 383.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 384.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 385.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 386.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 387.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 388.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 389.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 390.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 391.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 392.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 393.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 394.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 395.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 396.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 397.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 398.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 399.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 400.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 401.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 402.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 403.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 404.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 405.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 406.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 407.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 408.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 409.
) (C:\I\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package

(C:\I\tex/latex/base\t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)) (C:\I\tex/latex/ae\ae.sty
Package: ae 2001/02/12 1.3 Almost European Computer Modern

(C:\I\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package
 (C:\I\tex/latex/base\t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+aer on input line 105.

(C:\I\tex/latex/ae\t1aer.fd
File: t1aer.fd 1997/11/16 Font definitions for T1/aer.
)))) (pro1.aux)
\openout1 = `pro1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 4.
 (C:\I\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

(C:\I\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count91
\scratchdimen=\dimen105
\scratchbox=\box28
\nofMPsegments=\count92
\nofMParguments=\count93
\everyMPshowfont=\toks15
\MPscratchCnt=\count94
\MPscratchDim=\dimen106
\MPnumerator=\count95
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count96
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks16
) (C:\I\tex/latex/oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

(C:\I\tex/generic/oberdiek\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (C:\I\tex/latex/oberdiek\grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(C:\I\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)

(C:\I\tex/generic/oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)))
(C:\I\tex/latex/oberdiek\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
 (C:\I\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
(C:\I\tex/generic/oberdiek\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 (C:\I\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)))) (C:\I\tex/generic/oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/07/25 v0.30 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(C:\I\tex/generic/oberdiek\ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.
) (pro1-concordance.tex) (pro1.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2653 strings out of 492946
 35612 string characters out of 3135498
 92464 words of memory out of 3000000
 6530 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 5898 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,1n,25p,273b,80s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

No pages of output.

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe: dangling objects discarded, no output file produc
ed.

PDF statistics:
 1 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 5 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: what is the actual error message from tex, it would show which command is undefined.

Comment: I updated the error, its included in the plot

Comment: no that is just some unhelpful summary by your editor, the actual tex error in the log will show which command is undefined.

Comment: can you show the generated latex file that is passed to tex? most of us don't have R so can't run the example as posted.

Comment: Its Updated again.

Comment: that's better:-) `\quote@name` and `\unquote@name` were added to latex in the release last month, so it looks like you have a very new graphics package on an old latex, that isn't supposed to happen,

Comment: use a code block not quote for errors as the line breaks are important: that's what marks the undefined comand

Comment: can you delete all the R bits and just have `\begin{document}\end{document}` and then show the full log?

Comment: Updated again.. let me know what you find

Comment: What text editor are you using?